# Accessing the vector containing the dependent variable names after linear regression

Tags: r

I've done a linear regression on about 15 regressors and I'm trying to control the output in a script that I am writing. In the console, when I do

```
summary(lm1)$coefficients
```

I get a nice table of each regressor, its estimate, std. error, t-score and p-value. The ultimate goal is to print this table in a comma-delimited fashion so that I can open it in excel.

But when I do

```
summary(lm1)$coefficients[1,0]
```

to try to grab the name of the first regressor I get

```
numeric(0)
```

However, if I do

```
summary(lm1)$coefficients[1:3,0]
```

then I get the name of the first three regressors. I tried to create a vector with the names of all regressors by doing

```
mynames<-summary(lm1)$coefficients[,0]
```

sure enough, mynames contains the name of each regressor on a separate line but when i try to call

```
mynames[3]
```

for example, it returns NA.

The ultimate goal, as I stated, is to have the script I'm writing print a .csv file with the information I need - one row per regressor and for each row the name in col1, estimate in col2, std. err in col3, t-score in col4, and p-value in col5.

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)
coefTable <- summary(fit)$coef
colnames(coefTable)
#[1] "Estimate"   "Std. Error" "t value"    "Pr(>|t|)" 
rownames(coefTable)
#[1] "(Intercept)"  "Petal.Length"
```

But if you want to export to Excel, you can simply do this:

```
write.csv(coefTable, "test.csv")
```